# Discord bot not responding to command javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to make a Discord bot that responds to the user when they ask for help. Sadly I can't seem to get the bot to work. I am using Discord.JS on Node.JS. Any help would be welcome.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '[token removed]';

const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('K08 Help Bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message=>{

let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.lenght).split(" ");

switch(args[0]){
    case 'help':
        message.reply('HELLO');
    break;
}

})

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Have you done some sort of debugging yet ? We cannot know, out of no where, what's wrong here. Please refine your question, by adding what you've already test and what part, **exactly** is not working.

Comment: I have debugged the code and there seems to be nothign werong woth ot

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with it, why are we here ?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the issue:
`let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.lenght).split(" ");` - `length` is mistyped as `lenght`

On a side note: I've submitted an edit to hide your token in this question. For security, you should never share your token; it would allow someone to take over your bot!

Comment: Hahaha, it's fine! I make those mistakes sometimes ^^

Comment: @Mallagua in regards of what DaChickenKing said with your token, you might want to generate a new one. Chances are this one will not be valid anymore. Discord has a very good token leak detection system.